# GitHub API v3 Repsonse Different Based on Token

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to get the teams for the logged in user for some token. With a personal access token, everything looks ok:

```sh
# properly returns a bunch of teams
curl -H "Authorization: token ghp_123abc" 'https://api.github.com/user/teams'
[
  {
    "name": "abc",
    "id": 123,
    "node_id": "abc=",
    "slug": "123",
...
]
```

but when using an OAuth bearer token from an OAuth app, I get an empty `[]` from the API:

```sh
$ curl -H "Authorization: bearer gho_123abc" 'https://api.github.com/user/teams'
[

]
```

I know both tokens are valid since the response for `https://api.github.com/user` is the same regardless of token, but I just have no idea why the response would be different based on token (both have proper permissions to `read:org` as confirmed in the response headers)

Comment: Did you figure it out?